# On Minecraft, is it possible to breed my wolf with my friend's wolf? they're both already tamed

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Both my friend and I have one wolf on a realm and we want to breed them but are unsure if it will work.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? I think it should be possible though.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Official Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wolf) it's possible.

> Breeding two wolves that recognize someone else as an owner will cause
> the puppy to also be owned by the owner of the original two wolves. If
> two tamed wolves with different owners are bred, the puppy will be
> owned by the owner of the wolf bred last.